# How to use Type data in C#

Tags: c#, lambda

I have these lines :

```
var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<ClassOne, bool>>(eq, parameter);
var myList = db.ClassOne.Where(lambdaExpression).ToList();
```

I want to make those lines generic. My attempt is this:

```
mytype = typeof(ClassOne);
var lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda<Func<mytype, bool>>(eq, parameter);
var myList = db.mytype.Where(lambdaExpression).ToList();
```

But I get :

> 'mytype' is a variable but is used like a type

And

> 'Entities' does not contain a definition for 'mytype' and no extension
>   method 'mytype' accepting a first argument of type 'Entities' could be
>   found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

As you can see I want to pass the name of ClassOne via a variable. How can I do that? Thanks.

Comment: Create a method taking a `<T>` generic argument and use `T` inside, then call it with `<ClassOne>`. If you only have the type in a `Type` variable, you will need to use reflection as the bridge between the reflection world and the generic world.

Comment: You need reflection and it gets a little complex. "normally" (without reflection) the `T` type of generic must be known at compile time.

Comment: And in the end, while it is possible to do it, it will be quite useless... What would you do then with your `myList` of which you don't know its type? You would need to treat it as a `IEnumerable<object>` or to use other reflection to use it...

Comment: @xanatos I have `mytype`. It is always known. Wouldn't it be enough?

Comment: @jason `myType` is known at *runtime*, not at compile time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given a very simple:

```
public class ClassOne
{
    public int ID { get; set; }
}
```

Then we can:

```
public static class MyWhereHelper
{
    public static readonly MethodInfo WhereMethod = typeof(MyWhereHelper).GetMethod("Where", BindingFlags.Static | BindingFlags.Public);

    public static List<T> Where<T>(IQueryable<T> baseQuery, Expression<Func<T, bool>> where)
    {
        return baseQuery.Where(where).ToList();
    }
}
```

and then we use it like:

```
// Sample data
var db = new
{
    Data = new[]
    {
        new ClassOne { ID = 1 },
        new ClassOne { ID = 2 },
        new ClassOne { ID = 3 },
    }.AsQueryable(),
};

var mytype = typeof(ClassOne);

// Real code begins here
var parameter = Expression.Parameter(mytype);

var eq = Expression.Equal(Expression.Property(parameter, "ID"), Expression.Constant(2));

// In truth lambdaExpression is Expression<Func<mytype, bool>>
LambdaExpression lambdaExpression = Expression.Lambda(eq, parameter);

// Search of mytype inside db
// We look for the property that is implementing IQueryable<mytype>
// We could lookup by name if the name is .mytype
var iqueryableMyType = typeof(IQueryable<>).MakeGenericType(mytype);
var prop = db.GetType().GetProperties(BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.Public).Single(x => iqueryableMyType.IsAssignableFrom(x.PropertyType));

// db.mytype value
var propValue = prop.GetValue(db);

// MyWhereHelper.Where<mytype>
MethodInfo method = MyWhereHelper.WhereMethod.MakeGenericMethod(mytype);

var myList = (IEnumerable<object>)method.Invoke(null, new object[] { propValue, lambdaExpression });
```

We use reflection to find the `db.mytype` and for executing the query (note that we are using a "trick" here: we try to put everything that needs to use the `<mytype>` generic argument inside a single method, and use reflection *once* to execute that method. Clearly I'm speaking of `MyWhereHelper.Where<>`).

Inside `MyWhereHelper.Where<>` everything is strongly typed. Inside `MyWhereHelper.Where` we have a `List<T>` (that is a `List<mytype>`). But once we exit `MyWhereHelper.Where<>`, the caller is back again not knowing the exact type of `mytype` *at compile time*, so it can manipulate the result only as a `IEnumerable<object>` (or use once again reflection to manipulate it)

Answer (score 1):

This is a method I always use to get a `Expression<Func<type1, type2>>`. This the power of reflection:

```
        public static MethodInfo GetLambdaExpressionMethod(Type type1, Type type2)
        {
                return typeof(Expression).GetMethods().Where(x => x.Name == "Lambda").First()
                    .MakeGenericMethod(typeof(Func<,>).MakeGenericType(type1, type2));
        }
```

You can use it, like this:

```
var lambda = GetLambdaExpressionMethod(yourType, typeof(bool)).Invoke(null,
                    new object[] {
                        eq,
                        new ParameterExpression[] { parameter }
                    });
```

Now cast the lambda variable (that is object right now) to the `Expression<Func<yourType, bool>>` of yourType